# Difference between two dates with different timezones

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to obtain the difference between two dates but i'm stuck at converting a string into a date.

My code is:

```
    //create a date send it to the database as string
     Date currentDate = new Date(); // date looks like: Sat Sep 01 10:20:14 EEST 2012
     SaveToDB(currentDate.ToString());
```

At some point i;m trying to retrieve the date from the database:

```
       String dateStringFromDb = GetDateFromDB(); //Sat Sep 01 10:20:14 EEST 2012
       Date currentDate = new Date();

       //now i'm trying to covnert the dateStringFromDb into a Date, this throws an exception 

       Date dbDate = DateFormat.getInstance().parse(dateStringFromDb); //this throws exception

       long difference = currentDate.getTime() - dbDate.getTime(); // does this give me the correct difference in GMT even if timezones for the two dates are different?
```

Can you please point me to the correct solution?

Unfortunately the date from the database is retrieved as a String and i can't change that to another type. So i need to convert that string into Date().

EDIT:

Exception is :

```
java.text.ParseException: Format.parseObject(String) failed
    at java.text.Format.parseObject(Unknown Source)
    at main.Program.main(Program.java:20)
```

Comment: @SiB updated question with exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) API for your data and time related operation in Java. Handling `timezone` and all related conversion nuances are pretty easy using this API.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a DateFormat to match the string format being received

Eg.

```
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputString));
```

Once you have the both the dates in required format, then apply the date arithmetic operations

Other Format Specifiers for DateString can be found in 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html